# Add padding to edges of MKMapView in Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, padding

I've a MKMapView that shows a route between two points. These points can change so I wanted the MapView to zoom in that it shows the complete route. I fixed it with this code:

```
_map.SetVisibleMapRect(_routeOverlay.BoundingMapRect, true);
```

Now I want some padding around the edges because the route is now very close to the edges of the screen. How can I add padding to the MapView?

PS. I got it working in native iOS Xcode with this code but I can't get it working with Xamarin and C#:

```
[self.mapView2 setVisibleMapRect:[_routeOverlay boundingMapRect] edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed it after a few errors. I just had to add UIEdgeInsets to my SetVisibleMapRect() like this:

```
_map.SetVisibleMapRect (_routeOverlay.BoundingMapRect, new UIEdgeInsets(20, 20, 20, 20), true);
```

Thanks @Jason for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload for [SetVisibleMapRect](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.MapKit.MKMapView.SetVisibleMapRect%28MonoTouch.MapKit.MKMapRect,MonoTouch.UIKit.UIEdgeInsets,System.Boolean%29)() that does this:

```
public virtual void SetVisibleMapRect (MKMapRect mapRect, MonoTouch.UIKit.UIEdgeInsets edgePadding, bool animate)
```

Comment: This seems right but I don't know how to implement it. My code is inside a public method, where should I the overload?

Comment: You put it where your existing SetVisibleRect() method call is.  Just use the version with three arguments instead of the version with 2 args.